# "Loader.o: File not recognized: File format not recognized" Error

Tags: assembly, linker, g++, cygwin, kernel

I have a problem with the G++ `ld` command.

I'm trying to use this: `ld -T linker.ld -o Kernel.bin Loader.o Video.o Kernel.o`, but it's giving me the error: `Loader.o: File not recognized: File format not recognized`.

What's causing this error, and how can I fix it.

Comment: Where are your .o files coming from? g++?

Comment: What do the following commands print: `file Loader.o` and `uname -a`?

Comment: uname -a prints this:
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 TOBY-PC 20.1 (0.3/1/1) 1998-12-3 20:39:18 i686 unknown

And the file command is not recognized. @EmployedRussian